# Не получается создать куки PHP

Tags: php

Я пытаюсь создать куки , они не создаются . вот код PHP:

```
    elseif(isset($_POST["logined"])) {
    $login = $_POST["logined"];
    setcookie('login',$login,time() + (86400 * 5), "/"); }
```

Я пытаюсь вызвать эти куки позже на этой же странице , и это мне не удаётся , выводит null

Comment: Установленные куки видны только после перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: Даже так выводит null

Comment: а вы уверенны что isset($_POST["logined"]) its true ? проверяли (var_dump)? . Второе, как проверяете куку ?

Comment: Нe и так как куки высылаются с заголовками - убедитесь что либо нет вывода в страницу до установки кук либо работает output_buffering.

Comment: @Arsen Да , POST logined true так как я почти на 90% обрезал код и выделил то что вам нужно показать , все функции до установи куки работают , я проверяю куку так : if(isset($_COOKIE["login"])) {}